# TeXworks compiling glitch

Tags: compiling, texworks

I have a problem with TeXworks in which parts of the PDF file is not being shown.  It cuts off different sections of numerous pages on the document, so it makes it hard to inspect/read my output.  What can be done to fix this glitch? I will add that when I print to PDF, it shows the entire output as normal, however, I would like to be able to skip that step.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m not sure right now.  I’m asking for a professor who doesn’t use stack exchange.  He just left to eat.  What we did notice is that if you use the magnifying glass, you can see parts of the pages that are hidden. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @KJO zooming in and out doesn’t help.  A lot of pages are cut off with grey, rectangular sections are cut off.

Comment: @KJO it uses MikTeX on Windows 10

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have access to that at the moment.  The document is a book comprising of other files which are the chapters.  Another professor who is more familiar with TeX works will be assisting him.  Thank you for your help though @KJO

Comment: I don't use TeXworks. Could it be that TeXworks is showing you a portrait, A4 (or letter)-sized view while the pdf is another size (for ex. landscape)?

Comment: @HenkMetselaar we simply needed to close out and reopen TeXworks to fix the problem.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Closing the program and reopening it is all that was needed.